# Background image gradient in mpdf is reversed

Tags: php, pdf, mpdf

I have inline css like so

```
<td style='background-image: linear-gradient(to right, white,white,#f1f1f1)'>
```

In the browser it shows the two white colours on the left (as it should), and the #f1f1f1 on the right, but when mpdf generates a pdf, it is reversed.  The #f1f1f1 is on the left and the white colours are on the right.  Does mpdf require slightly different syntax?  Or is this a bug?

Browser

[image]

PDF

[image]

Comment: What browser, on which OS, are you using? They are not all the same. It seems to me that mpdf does it correctly, namely the order is to the left.

Comment: I'm using both Chrome and Edge on Windows 11.

Comment: if I [test your code](https://codepen.io/kikosoft/pen/KKGepGL?editors=1000), and look at it with Chrome in Windows 11, the non-white bit appears on the left, not the right. Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which actually does what you show in your images. Actual working code is worth more than a 1000 images.

Comment: Sorry, I just went back and tested it again.  I had my sample code wrong in my OP.  I just fixed it.  It's actually "to right" not "to left".  And I confirmed that mpdf is still reversing it.

Comment: OK, I believe you. There's a whole list of [Supported CSS](https://mpdf.github.io/css-stylesheets/supported-css.html), `linear-gradient` is in there, and it seems that mPDF gets this one wrong. First make sure you're using the latest version, and if the problem persists you can [open an issue on Github](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf.github.io/issues) about it. However, you should also read [this warning about CSS support and development state](https://mpdf.github.io/#about-css-support-and-development-state): _"... better and/or newer CSS support will most likely not be implemented."_.

Comment: This was a relatively simple fix, it is now present in upstream of mPDF and will be released with the next patch version.